# How to upgrade from Ruby 1.9.2p0 to ruby 1.9.2p180 without rvm?

Tags: ruby

I have searching around for upgrading ruby 1.9.2p0 to ruby 1.9.2p180 as I got some compatibility issues in my application. I searched on web and studied but am unable to do it. I know that this has already been discussed a lot, but still I'm unable to figure it out. Also I don't want to use **rvm**. So looking for fast responses with simple ways to upgrade ruby 1.9.2p180.

Comment: @Dogbert ...using apt-get install commands..

Comment: It helps if you mention what operating system you're using. It is Ubuntu, Debian, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to the [ruby site](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/), and download it. Extract it, `cd` to the extracted directory, then do as usual:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Either look for another universe that has a more recent package or install from source.